# How can I query an API to refresh the data in a dataframe and perform calculations against said data without stopping Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using httr and jsonlite to query an API.  This data is made tidy and then a number of calculations are made.  The data is then rendered with the Shiny app.  All works well except for having to stop the Shiny app in order to query the API for fresh data.  Is there a way to query the API and perform said calculations without having to stop Shiny?  My goal is to query the API every 5 minutes and display the fresh data via Shiny.  I apologize if this an elementary question but I am relatively new with Shiny.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `shiny::invalidateLater`.

Comment: Thanks @ Limey.  I may be wrong but I don't think this will execute the code within an R script that queries the API and performs calculations on data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... I don't think this will execute the code within an R script that queries the API ...": you are mistaken.

You've provided no details of your API or calculations, so I simulate the call to the API simply by generating a random tibble.  Also, to save you waiting five minutes to see the data change, I query "the API" every two seconds.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

queryAPI <- function() {
  tibble(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  apiData <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(2000)
    queryAPI()
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({ apiData() })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
    apiData() %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```